# H2 in-memory database error "Data conversion error converting" when using UUID as primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, h2, slick

I got the following error when using UUID as primary key with Slick with H2 in-memory database. I've tried to debug this for days, but no luck:

```
Data conversion error converting "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"
```

Here's the code that can reproduce this issue:

```
import java.util.UUID

import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object Main {

  class Tasks(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Option[UUID])](tag, "tasks") {
    def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name")

    def id = column[UUID]("id", O.SqlType("UUID"), O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def * = (name, id ?)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=PostgreSQL", driver = "org.h2.Driver")

    try {
      val tasks = TableQuery[Tasks]
      println("Create table: " + tasks.schema.create.statements.mkString("|"))
      val setupAction: DBIO[Unit] = DBIO.seq(
        tasks.schema.create,
        tasks.+=("foo", None)
      )

      Await.result(db.run(setupAction), Duration.Inf)
    } finally db.close
  }
}
```

Can anyone provide some help here?

**--- Updates ---**

The table creation query is like:

```
create table "tasks" (
  "name" VARCHAR                                              NOT NULL,
  "id"   UUID GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

The full stack trace is like:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"; SQL statement:
insert into "tasks" ("name")  values (?) [22018-187]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:902)
    at org.h2.value.Value.getLong(Value.java:443)
    at org.h2.table.Column.updateSequenceIfRequired(Column.java:339)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:331)
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:737)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:151)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:78)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:254)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:157)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:143)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$SingleInsertAction$$anonfun$run$7.apply(JdbcActionComponent.scala:507)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$SingleInsertAction$$anonfun$run$7.apply(JdbcActionComponent.scala:504)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.withPreparedStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:347)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.withPreparedStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:407)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl.preparedInsert(JdbcActionComponent.scala:498)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$SingleInsertAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:504)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$SimpleJdbcDriverAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:32)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$SimpleJdbcDriverAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:29)
    at slick.dbio.DBIOAction$$anon$4$$anonfun$run$3.apply(DBIOAction.scala:214)
    at slick.dbio.DBIOAction$$anon$4$$anonfun$run$3.apply(DBIOAction.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at slick.dbio.DBIOAction$$anon$4.run(DBIOAction.scala:214)
    at slick.dbio.DBIOAction$$anon$4.run(DBIOAction.scala:212)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.liftedTree1$1(DatabaseComponent.scala:237)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(DatabaseComponent.scala:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:854)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: What does Postgres have to do with this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good question, I'm using Postgres in my application. The H2 database is used just in unit tests.

Comment: Another example why using a different DBMS for testing and production is not a good idea...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried to "import H2.api._" in Tasks class, but it's still showing the same issue.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Then how to unit test a Postgres application?

Comment: @SexyNerd Could you post the stack trace and the "create table" statement please? You get that by running the "script" SQL statement in H2.

Comment: @SexyNerd Side note: For performance reasons, I would avoid using a randomly generated UUID (or any other randomly distributed data) as the primary key of a table, if you expect the table has more than about 1000 rows. Using sequence numbers or similar is _much_ faster.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Just updated with the stack trace and the create table query. I will take a look the sequence number.

Comment: @ThomasMueller I found this problem only happens when the id is defined as ```O.AutoInc``` while the data being inserted has ```id = None```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a strange "create table" statement with a sequence of type UUID. No database supports that. You would need to use for example:

```
create table tasks (
  name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  id UUID DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

insert into tasks(name) values('Hello');
select * from tasks;
```

But randomly generated primary keys are slow, I suggest to go back to regular sequences.

P.S. the same question was asked here: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/303

Comment: After some struggles, I decided to go back to sequence numbers. The table creation code was generated by Slick. Not sure if this is an issue of Slick's h2 driver.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Thomas answer, another option would be to change the type from `uuid` to `begint`:

```
create table "tasks" (
  "name" VARCHAR                                                NOT NULL,
  "id"   BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

*When the table is generated by Slick / Hibernate / etc, you may not be able to write your own SQL. Changing the type though could be viable alternative.*