# Cannot use setArray JDBC (integer) with H2 Database

Tags: java, arrays, jdbc, h2

I want to put an array of integers in my jdbc query with H2 database.

```
Integer[] list = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
            String query = "SELECT EXAMPLE FROM DATA WHERE EXAMPLE IN (?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = GestionBDD.getConexionBD().prepareStatement(query);
            Array array = GestionBDD.getConexionBD().createArrayOf("int", list);

            ps.setArray(1, array);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                // DO THINGS 
            }
```

But doest not work, I am getting this exception : org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "(1,2,3)"; SQL statement:

I am using H2 database.
Can you help me please?

Comment: Check, it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693849/h2-in-memory-database-error-data-conversion-error-converting-when-using-uuid-a?rq=1

Comment: what is EXAMPLE defined in the database as INT or VARCHAR ?

Comment: Is that way: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DATA (EXAMPLE int auto_increment)

Comment: can you try `GestionBDD.getConexionBD().createArrayOf("INTEGER", list);`

Comment: I tried too, but doesn't work. It seems that is not the error

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3724272/2144390) for how to do it with H2.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my JDBC utilities to work with JDBC IN array parameters easily:

**1. If Maven, add the below dependency into your pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.appslandia</groupId>
      <artifactId>appslandia-common</artifactId>
      <version>7.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

**2. If no maven, [download this jar file](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/appslandia/appslandia-common/7.9/appslandia-common-7.9.jar)**

**3. Fix your code ( Works all DBMS guaranteed )**

```
static final Sql EXAMPLE_SQL 
          = new Sql("SELECT EXAMPLE FROM DATA WHERE EXAMPLE IN :example_array");

StatementImpl stat = new StatementImpl(GestionBDD.getConexionBD(), EXAMPLE_SQL);

stat.setIntArray("example_array", new int[] {1, 2, 3} );

ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
    // DO THINGS 
}

rs.close(); stat.close();
```

**4. Named parameters / Null parameters**

```
final Sql sampleSql 
       = new Sql("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE a=:int_a AND b=:str_b)

StatementImpl stat = new StatementImpl(conn, sampleSql);

stat.setInt("int_a", int_value);
stat.setInt2("int_a", null_value);
stat.setString("str_b", str_value);
// ...
```

**5. Some Notes**

- Parameter name supported. No more ? in your query
- Parameter in Sql need to start with : (Like JPA parameters)
- IN Array parameter in Sql must be in this syntax  IN :param_name