# Java Prepared SELECT SQL Statement Using Sets

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I am running a `SELECT` query using JDBC which itself has a few subqueries. One of these subqueries returns a column of data which I then process as an `ArrayList`. Due to error handling, I prepare the subquery and run it separately then produce the java String in the form `"(item_1, item_2, ... , item_n)"`.

Note the tuple elements are INTEGERS.

My overarching query is in the form of a `PreparedStatement` where I look to populate the `?` using my subquery result.

```java
String subqueryResult = "(1, 2, 3)";

// ...

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName in ?");
stmt.setString(subqueryResult);
```

I get the SQL 1064 error which then states that my query looks like `WHERE columnName in ''(1, 2, 3)'`.

I understand that the literal quotes are unbalanced, but even if they are balanced we cannot perform an `IN` clause on a string.

How would I go about safely populating the `PreparedStatement` so that the resulting query looks like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName in (1, 2, 3)`?

Comment: AFAIK plain JDBC doesn't support that so you'd have to use a collection of strings and a matching number of `?` parameters in the query, i.e. build the query dynamically and then set the value of each individual parameter. Alternatively a framework could handle that for you (I know JPA  implementations do it but there are others for sure).

Comment: You would need to build your query first based on the elements of your set, then setting the parameters, for example:
`String s = "( ";
 for (String x : set){
      s += "?,";
 }`

Comment: @vc73 currently, my set is built as a String and does in fact have the correct form "`(item_1, item_2, item_3)`" but then the SQL looks like `[...] WHERE columnName in '(item_1, item_2, item_3)'`. How do I get rid of those pesky single quotes?

Comment: Is `columnName` a character column?  If so, you need single quotes around each entry in the in clause.

Comment: @Andrew it is just a generic table column name I used for the example (because I can't upload any of the actual code). I have just edited my question to state the type of variables inside the tuple

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135349/cannot-use-setarray-jdbc-integer-with-h2-database/56350387#56350387

Comment: `PreparedStatement` doesn't support what you are trying to do. It's like trying to put a square peg into a round hole. You can use a `java.sql.Statement` and simply concatenate the string "(1, 2, 3)" to the string "SELECT * ..."